# Running multi platform Kotlin test in IntelliJ produces No JDK specified error

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have several tests in common module for multi platform Kotlin project. When I execute those tests using gradle, e.g. `./gradlew :android:test`, they all go through and the tests run.

I have now encountered a more complicated problem where I would like to debug an actual test in IntelliJ. Unfortunately, upon selecting the debug option in IntelliJ, I get an *No JDK specified* error.

[image: No JDK specified]

I am using the following dependencies for testing:

```
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common:$kotlin_version"
```

with `$kotlin_version` being **1.2.41**.

The common module settings looks like this:

[image: Common module settings]

SDKs section also correctly recognises JDKs:

[image: SDKs]

I have tried changing the Module SDK from Kotlin SDK to java, however IntelliJ then wants me to require jUnit for test execution, which I would prefer not to, if possible.

Is there a way how to make the debugger run in IntelliJ for the Kotlin code?

Comment: Issue is reported on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23884

Comment: @y.bedrov Thank you for the link, I have however found another solution which I believe should be the correct approach. Further explanation is in the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

Just like it does not make sense to execute tests using Gradle in the common module alone, e.g. `./gradlew :common:test` and the tests need to be executed for a specific platform `./gradlew :android:test`, because the common module might contain `expect`ed declarations which are supposed to be implemented per platform using the `actual` keyword, it also does not make sense to debug in the common module directly.

Instead, for such purposes, the test to be debugged must be placed in a specific platform module, for my purpose I have chosen the Android module, and then it can be executed and debugged.

As I have mentioned, this approach is necessary because in the Android module the `expect`ed structures are actually replaced by the `actual` implementations.